# How to get the rowid in a TRIGGER for another table in SQLite

Tags: trigger, insert, sqlite

## Given

the below schema

```
CREATE TABLE Item (
    _id         INTEGER      NOT NULL,
    name        NVARCHAR     NOT NULL,
    parent      INTEGER          NULL
        CONSTRAINT fk_Recursive
            REFERENCES Item(_id),
    PRIMARY KEY(_id AUTOINCREMENT)
);
CREATE TABLE Container (
    _id         INTEGER      NOT NULL,
    name        NVARCHAR     NOT NULL,
    root        INTEGER      NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT fk_Container_root
            REFERENCES Item(_id),
    PRIMARY KEY(_id AUTOINCREMENT)
);
```

### Used in client

e.g. Java equivalent prepared statements with `?`s and params of these two statements:

```
INSERT INTO Item VALUES (1, 'ROOT', NULL);
INSERT INTO Container VALUES (1, 'My Box', 1);
```

## Question

Is it possible to write a trigger (or anything else) without client code (only SQL) which achieves the above results with only

```
INSERT INTO Container(name) VALUES('My Box');
```

Note: Of course the client code will retrieve the new `rowid` for the inserted `Container`, but I don't care about the new (root) `Item`, that will be used much later by reading from `Container`.

The trigger would be along the lines of:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Rooter
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON Container WHEN (root IS NULL) BEGIN
    SET newRoot = INSERT INTO Item(name, parent) VALUES ('ROOT', NULL);
    INSERT INTO Container VALUES (new._id, new.name, newRoot);
END;
```

Changing `Container.root` to `NULL` and creating an `AFTER INSERT TRIGGER` shouldn't be an option. But then I guess the same problem of getting the `Item`'s `rowid` would still stand.

Comment: You cannot have INSTEAD OF triggers on tables; you must update the record afterwards. As for getting the last inserted rowid, read the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#last_insert_rowid).

Comment: Ah, thanks, those looked like C functions because they were not uppercase :) I should have tried `select last_insert_rowid();`...

Comment: [Triggers may be created on views, as well as ordinary tables, by specifying INSTEAD OF in the CREATE TRIGGER statement.](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html#instead_of_trigger), why does it say so if it's not possible?

Comment: Because a view is not a table.

Comment: Ahaa, fancy language sometimes gets me: I thought "as well as" means "and also", but it means ["in addition to"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%3Aas%20well%20as). Now I see how it says "Triggers may also be created on views, by ...", thank you! I hope you see the possible confusion there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [CL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/11397)'s suggestion to take another look at [`last_insert_rowid()`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#last_insert_rowid) and now that it's clear that [`INSTEAD OF` triggers are only for `VIEW`s](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html#instead_of_trigger) (see question's comments), here's a working version:

```
-- We need a view to create the trigger on
CREATE VIEW Container_Auto AS select * from Container;

-- Since it's automatic we need to check if we need to create a root
CREATE TRIGGER Rooter_Auto
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON Container_Auto WHEN (new.root IS NULL) BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Item(name, parent) VALUES ('ROOT', NULL);
    INSERT INTO Container VALUES (new._id, new.name, last_insert_rowid());
END;
-- If we don't need a root (i.e. the client supplied it), just pass the values through
CREATE TRIGGER Rooter_Transparent
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON Container_Auto WHEN (new.root IS NOT NULL) BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Container VALUES (new._id, new.name, new.root);
END;

-- Tests
INSERT INTO Item VALUES (1, 'ROOT', NULL);
INSERT INTO Container VALUES (1, 'My Box', 1);
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Container(name) VALUES('Won''t work');
INSERT INTO Container_Auto(name) VALUES('All Automatic');
INSERT INTO Container_Auto(_id, name) VALUES(100, 'Specific ID');
INSERT INTO Container_Auto(name, root) VALUES('Specific root', 1);

-- Results
SELECT '---- Container ----';
SELECT * from Container;
SELECT '---- Item ----';
SELECT * from Item;
```

Output with comments:

```
---- Container ----
1|My Box|1          -- everything as we specified
                    -- note the OR IGNORE failed because root IS NULL
3|All Automatic|2   -- the failed insert incremented the rowid as well as created a new root
100|Specific ID|3   -- the supplied _id is used, new root is created
101|Specific root|1 -- the supplied root is used, _id is incremented
---- Item ----
1|ROOT|             -- created manually
2|ROOT|             -- created automatically by INTO Container_Auto(name)
3|ROOT|             -- created automatically by INTO Container_Auto(_id, name)
```

Notes:

- Using `INSERT INTO Table VALUES` format helps to catch schema modification bugs since when a new column is added the `INSERT` will fail instead of ignoring the new column.
- One can still use the `Container` table to insert into.
- **`last_insert_rowid()` doesn't work when used after an `INSERT INTO` on a view with `INSTEAD OF INSERT`, i.e. after `INSERT INTO Container_Auto`, you'll have to requery the inserted row :(**